# Symfony 4 nor install correct version

Tags: symfony4

So now I have been working with symfony 3.3
Try to follow the instructions to install symfony 4 with composer but install symfony 3.4.6
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton "dev-master"
```

if it doesn't work, so you should update your composer version

```
composer self-update
```

if the problem remains clear composer cache and retry

```
composer clearcache
```

Comment: Hello
I have the composer updated as shown below

C:\Symfony4>composer -V
Composer version 1.6.3 2018-01-31 16:28:17

when I try to create a master of symfony 4 the composer shows:

C:\Symfony4>composer create-project symfony/skeleton "dev-master"
Installing symfony/skeleton (v3.4.5)
  - Installing symfony/skeleton (v3.4.5): Loading from cache
Created project in dev-master
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

so it generates a symfony 3.4.5
Is there a way to fix it?
regards

Comment: I had installed php 7.1 then update to 7.2 and it worked correctly. I guess that should be the reason.
regards