# How can I install Symfony 4 instead of Symfony 3.4?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4

I try to install Symfony 4 [as per the documentation](https://symfony.com/download) but keep ending up with version 3.4.

How can I install the correct version?

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
$ php -v | head -n1
PHP 7.0.27-0+deb9u1 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2018 13:51:52) ( NTS )

$ composer clearcache
$ composer self-update
You are already using composer version 1.6.4 (stable channel).

$ composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project
$ cd my_project && bin/console about | head -n4
 -------------------- ---------------------------------------------------- 
  Symfony                                                                  
 -------------------- ---------------------------------------------------- 
  Version              3.4.9
```

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851068/symfony-4-nor-install-correct-version) it was suggested you need php 7.2, how could I check that? The current Debian version seems to be 7.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony 4.0's `symfony/website-skeleton` package has a `composer.json` states a requirement of `"php": "^7.1.3"`.

https://github.com/symfony/website-skeleton/blob/4.0/composer.json

(So does Symfony 4.0 itself, incidentally: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v4.0.0/composer.json)

You'll need to upgrade PHP to at least that version to use it. Until then, Composer will give you the latest version of the package that matches your PHP version.

The [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html) state this as well.

> Symfony 4.0 requires PHP 7.1.3 or higher to run, in addition to other minor requirements.